# Getting the current device time

Tags: c#, .net, wia

I'm using WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) to grab photos from a camera.  Using WIA 2.0, .net 4 C#, my test device is a Nikon D90 (yup, I have it actually plugged in).  So the scenario is:

1. User has camera plugged into PC
2. User takes a photo from the camera itself
3. My application downloads the image via WIA

All of the above is working.

The problem I'm having is getting the current time from the device itself.  The first time I get the time from the device I get the correct time, all good.  If I run my application again, WIA seems to cache the time I got earlier and returns that, which is useless.

```
// use the WIA.DeviceManager to get the deviceInfo (not shown)
var device = deviceInfo.Connect();
var prop = device.Properties["Device Time"];
Vector deviceTimeVector = (Vector)prop.get_Value();
var deviceTime = deviceTimeVector.Date;
```

Does anyone who's done some work with WIA know how to reliably get the current time from a device?  I've tried a synchronise but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
_device.ExecuteCommand(WIA.CommandID.wiaCommandSynchronize);
```

Open to suggestions too.  I was thinking my only other way would be to "calibrate" the device by taking a test shot, checking what the time taken of that picture was but there's problems with this too.

Please let me know if you need any information.